# Rails - How to deal with multiple association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Let's say I have a model, named **Student**,

A model named **Test** (the tests students take at school)

An association model named **StudentTest**, which says when the particular student has done a particular test, under what circumstances, etc..

A model named **Questions**, which will be used by the tests

An association model named **QuestionTest**, which says which questions will be on which tests.

Finally, a model named **StudentAnswer**, which contains a reference to QuestionTest and a reference to Student.

If I have

```
st = StudentTest.first
```

I can do:

```
st.test.questions_test
```

to get the test questions assigned to that student.

However, if I want the answers of that student, I cannot do this:

```
st.test.questions_test.student_answers
```

Because though it will get the answers that are related to those question_test_id, it will not be related to that student_id alone.

An alternative would be

```
st.test.question_test.student_answers.where(student_id: st.id).all
```

or

```
st.student.student_answers.where(test_id: st.test_id).all
```

But it seems too redundant have to repeat the variable st just to get it's id.

My question is: is there any association that I can declare to make it possible to retrive the answers as:

```
st.student_answers
```

or something like it?

**EDIT 1: What I was thinking of the use of relations**

I was thinking of something like:

**student_test.rb**

```
has_many :questions_test, through: :test
has_many :student_answers, through: [:questions_test, :student]
```

But of course, this has syntax error. Through would only accept one argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic diagram of how I understand it:

```
  Questions                Test                Student
           \            /        \            /       \
            QuestionTest          StudentTest          |
                  |                                    |
                  \--------------StudentAnswer--------/
```

If you start with:

```
st = StudentTest.first
```

Then you can get the answer for a specific student like so:

```
student_answers = st.student.answers_for(st.test)
```

Your `answers_for` method would look like this:

```
# student.rb
has_many :student_answers

def answers_for(test)
  student_answers.where(test: test).all
end
```

This allows you to pull all the answers from the specified test.

Comment: You understood my question correctly. This is the diagram. However, please look at my edit. Do you think I could accomplish this only with declaring relations, like the has many through?

Comment: I looked at the edit. This was my first thought too, but you see, if I do st.student_answers, it will give records that match only question_test_id, that means, I'll get answers for those questions, but not necessarily they will be from the specific student

Comment: The problem is that it should be related to both "st" questions_test and "st" student... I wanted to use "has many through" but "through" would only take one argument. Do you still think there's a way to do this with relations only?

Comment: Yes, making another edit. It's getting clearer and clearer

Comment: ArgumentError: Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type

Comment: Sorry, my mind slipped. `conditions` is deprecated for Rails 4. There is another workaround, which I'll add to my answer. I recommend `answers_for`, or creating a scope.

Comment: I accepted the answer for the answer_for... The has_many, as I was thinking, did not work... please update the answer to add that last part as "Failed" so other people will know. Thank you for your attention to my question :)

Comment: Also, answers_for doesn't need an attribute. You can call self.test_id